# How to retrive all options of all selects of a form in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to retrieve all the options selected of different selects within the same form with Jquery. By the way, the main goal is to retrieve the result of a submit.
The situation is something like that:

```
 <form id="myform" action="result.php" method="post">
    <select id="select1" name="select[]">
        <option value="A1">1</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <select id="select2" name="select[]">
        <option value="A1">1</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Within result.php, there is this function:

```
 if (!empty($_POST['select'])) {

    $selects = array();

    foreach ($_POST['select'] as $check) {
        $selects[] = $check;

    }
    if(count($selects)==0){
    echo "ERROR";}else{echo "OK"}
}
```

How Can I display an alert, with the result of echo of result.php, in the page where there is the form?

Comment: That looks like invalid HTML. Your ID's cannot be that. Please validate it, fix it, and try again.

Comment: You can use the selector 'option:select', like this:


    $('option:selected').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());
    });

Comment: I want to get all the options of the all selects selected of the form !

Comment: are you actually missing a `$` on your `selects` in `if(count(selects)==0)`?

Comment: That's not the problem. I mean the code I post, it is just an example of my need ! the result.php is more complex of that, but the result is just a string from an echo :)

Comment: Does result.php do any validation/processing with the selects that would prevent you from getting/displaying the results in strictly javascript/jquery?

Comment: The result.php always shows an echo, because it makes some check about the options sent.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the selects be named the same and/or remain generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some deciphering and I am assuming you need to keep your selects generic. Instead of using the invalid `select[]` naming, I retrieved all of the `<select>` via jQuery. Not sure if that fits the bill or not.

If you need to keep them named `select[]`, I would recommend looking at [Get values from multiple select boxes with same name? Including its value with jquery and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931368/get-values-from-multiple-select-boxes-with-same-name-including-its-value-with-j) in addition to the solution below.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#mySubmitAjax').click(function(e) {
                var selects = $('select');
                var selects_results = "";

                selects.each(function(i,v) {
                    selects_results += i + '=' + $(v).val() + '&';
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'result.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: selects_results,
                    success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm">
        <select>
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
        </select>

        <select>
            <option value="1">one</option>
            <option value="2">two</option>
        </select>

        <button type="button" id="mySubmitAjax">Submit w/AJAX</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**result.php**

```
<?php
    $post = $_POST;
    $results = [];

    foreach($post as $p) {
        $results[] = $p['v'];
    }

    print json_encode($results);

?>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works ! Do you think it is a good solution ? I mean with this solution, I can work with Android, Windows Phone, iOs e web platform, with the same result.php file !

Answer (score 1):

When executing the PHP code, you're on the server side again. Whereever you build the HTML output, this is where you could, e.g., include a script tag created by PHP which does something like this:

```
<script>
    alert("<?php echo $selectResults; ?>");
</script>
```

This is horribly unmaintainable (you shouldn't have PHP code mixed up this way in your HTML output), but since I don't know how you create your pages, I hope you get the idea.

It is very important to understand where which code is executed, and since you're on the PHP, i.e., server side, there is no straightforward way to "send" JavaScript alerts back to the client (ignoring WebSockets here).

Another way is to post the result via AJAX to the server, get the server's response ("ERROR", "OK", or whatever), and use this in your AJAX callback to alert the message. Again, since I don't know how you build your pages, I cannot tell which is more feasible.

Comment: With jquery, I can send a post and get the result back and show it with an alert. The problem is that the data to post to result.php are within a form.

Comment: Ok, so the part "How Can I display an alert, with the result of echo of result.php, in the page where there is the form" you actually already know? I don't understand your question. If you send the POST, everything turns up within `$_POST` on the PHP side, where you can check the values, return whatever result you want, and display it with an alert. Actually, I don't think you can have two select tags with the same name `select[]`, should probably be `select1[]` and `select2[]`.