# How to capture the data of different fields in form using same name tag?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

In the below code, I have two dropdowns, while posting the data I have to capture the value of any one of the dropdowns. so, I am using the name field to capture the data. but, the problem here is I am able to capture the data only one dropdown value which I labeled has "weekly" if I want to capture the value of another dropdown which I labeled has "monthly" I am not able to capture that.

```html
    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md" >
      <div class=" shadow bg-white rounded">
        <div class="card-header">
          <p>Frequency </p>
        </div>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="frequency">
              <label class="custom-control-label pointer">
                Daily
              </label>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
             <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
               <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" >
               <label class="custom-control-label pointer">
                 Weekly
               </label>
               <select  class="form-control" name="frequency">
                   <option value = '' selected hidden>Choose </option>
                   <option value="Weekly - Sunday">Sunday </option>
                   <option value="Weekly - Monday">Monday </option>
                   <option value="Weekly - Tuesday">Tuesday </option>
                   <option value="Weekly - Wednessday">Wednessday </option>
                   <option value="Weekly - Thursday">Thursday </option>
                   <option value="Weekly - Friday">Friday </option>
                   <option value="Weekly - Saturday">Saturday </option>
               </select>
             </div>
           </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
           <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
              <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox">
              <label class="custom-control-label pointer">
                Monthly
              </label>
              <select  class="form-control" name="frequency">
                  <option selected hidden>Choose </option>
                  {% for days in range(1,32) %}
                    <option value="monthly - {{days}}">{{days}}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
              </select>
            </div>
          </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This is most likely Javascript problem, please include the appropriate code.

Comment: When you have repeated names, you have to give them array-style names: [here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17344480/12037439)

Comment: you need to follow approach as suggested by @rawk or you have to give different names for the dropdowns and then access it.

Comment: Visit it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931368/get-values-from-multiple-select-boxes-with-same-name-including-its-value-with-j